# How can I INSERT into same table twice?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, if-statement, insert

I'm creating a booking system (Airport Taxi Firm) which initially creates a booking storing the customers contact & billing details etc, it then uses the ID to post the journey information into another table, and if return details were included it then creates another record in the same JOBS table with the return journey. I am using a IF statement to check if return details have been submitted. However, it only inserts the first journey, not the return. See Code below.

Any ideas?

I also appreciate that it is highly likely I am going about a strange way to achieve my outcome, so any criticism and pointers are also welcomed.

Thanks

```
<?php


$customer_title          =  $_POST['customer_title'];
$customer_first_name     =  $_POST['customer_first_name'];
$customer_last_name      =  $_POST['customer_last_name'];
$billing_address         =  $_POST['billing_address'];
$customer_tel            =  $_POST['customer_tel'];
$customer_mobile         =  $_POST['customer_mobile'];
$customer_email          =  $_POST['customer_email'];
$passengers              =  $_POST['passengers'];
$cases                   =  $_POST['cases'];
$return_flight_number    =  $_POST['return_flight_number'];
$price                   =  $_POST['price'];
$pickup_date             =  $_POST['pickup_date'];
$pickup_time             =  $_POST['pickup_time'];
$pickup_address          =  $_POST['pickup_address'];
$pickup_destination      =  $_POST['pickup_destination'];
$return_date             =  $_POST['return_date'];
$return_time             =  $_POST['return_time'];
$return_pickup           =  $_POST['return_pickup'];
$return_destination      =  $_POST['return_destination'];
$booking_notes           =  $_POST['booking_notes'];

$booking_status          =  Confirmed;
$account_number          =  9999;
$authorised              =  N;


$booking_date            = 0;
$null_date               = '0000-00-00'; 


include('../assets/db_connection.php');

mysql_select_db("airporthopper");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO bookings(customer_name, billing_address, account_number, contact_tel, contact_mob, contact_email,
            party_pax, party_cases, booking_notes, price, booking_agent, booking_date, booking_status, authorised)
VALUES('$customer_title $customer_first_name $customer_last_name', '$billing_address', $account_number, '$customer_tel', '$customer_mobile', '$customer_email', '$passengers', '$cases', '$booking_notes', '$price', 'Danny Green', '$booking_date',
    '$booking_status', '$authorised'   )");



$booking_ref = mysql_insert_id();

mysql_query("INSERT INTO jobs(booking_ref, pickup_date, pickup_time, pickup_address, destination_address, scheduled)VALUES('$booking_ref', '$pickup_date', '$pickup_time', '$pickup_address', '$pickup_destination', 'N')");

if ($return_date != $null_date) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO jobs(booking_ref, pickup_date, pickup_time, pickup_address, destination_address, return, scheduled)VALUES('$booking_ref', '$return_date', '$return_time', '$return_pickup', '$return_destination', 'Y' , 'N')");
 }




?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @JohnConde: Are you using some unobtrusive browser extension or equivalent to quickly paste this as a snippet? I 'd like to get on board if only I knew how.

Comment: @Jon. I got the text from [here](https://gist.github.com/3881905) and use Evernote to cut & paste it.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't anything like UNIQUE on booking_ref?

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions like someone said, but more importantly do not use unescaped POST variables in the query. That's a major security threat right there.

Comment: Try checking you are getting into if($return_date != $null_date){}  or not.

Comment: Thanks John, looked at the tutorial link and have now implemented use of PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "if ($return_date != $null_date) {", use:

```
if (strtotime($return_date) > 0) {
```

Also I hope the 'booking_ref' column in 'jobs' table has no **unique index** associated with it.